# Creating json object using multiple arrays

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a SINGLE data obj to send to an API, however I need to build the json obj using multiple arrays. The below code will log the information correctly, but when creating the data obj only uses the first iteration. Does anyone know how i could have the data print for each count of my array?

```
 var quantity = [1, 2, 3];
 var color    = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
 var shape    = ['square', 'rectangle', 'circle'];

 //note, the arrays will always be the same length

 var len = quantity.length;

 for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
     var data = {
                 "theQuantity" : quantity[x];
                 "theColor"    : color[x];
                 "theShape"    : shape[x];
                };
```

desired output

```
 data = {
                 "theQuantity" = quantity[x];
                 "theColor"    = color[x];
                 "theShape"    = shape[x];
                 "theQuantity" = quantity[x];
                 "theColor"    = color[x];
                 "theShape"    = shape[x];
                 "theQuantity" = quantity[x];
                 "theColor"    = color[x];
                 "theShape"    = shape[x];
  }
```

Comment: When defining objects, use `"key" : "value"` (note the `:` instead of `=`).

Comment: Also, you cannot have duplicate keys in an object.  Do you want `theQuantity`, `theColor` and `theShape` to contain an *array* of values?  What API are you using, and does it even let you send it multiple values?

Comment: Another note: If you send a JSON string that contains multiple keys with the same name, only the last will be used.

Comment: i'm aware of the issue with multiple keys. The actual code prints much different from this, however the structure is the same. I am just having an issue with the loop.

Comment: Well, in your loop you are *redefining* `data` each time.  And if the structure is the same, then your desired result is impossible.  What problem *exactly* are you trying to solve here.  Depending on the API, you may not be able to combine multiple elements into one call.

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't just want something like: `var data = {"theQuantity": quantity, "theColor": color, "theShape": shape};` (without any loop)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have the same key on the same level, the key is "theColor", "theShape"...

So you need to have an structure like this

```
[
    {
        "theQuantity": 1,
        "theColor": "blue",
        "theShape": "square"
    },
    {
        "theQuantity": 2,
        "theColor": "red",
        "theShape": "rectangle"
    },
    {
        "theQuantity": 3,
        "theColor": "green",
        "theShape": "circle"
    }
]
```

so you then can make a loop on this and access to any of them, here is a working example that generate that structure

```
 var quantity = [1, 2, 3];
 var color    = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
 var shape    = ['square', 'rectangle', 'circle'];

 //note, the arrays will always be the same length

 var len = quantity.length;
 var data = []
 for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
   var element = {
                 "theQuantity" : quantity[x],
                 "theColor"    : color[x],
                 "theShape"    : shape[x]
   };
   data.push(element);
 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

[working example](https://codepen.io/xploshioOn/pen/pPezNE)

Comment: So doing the structure as above, i could post 3 data objects on the same post?

Comment: yes, you just push data and will have the 3 elements so you can iterate that json on the server